# KQL - How do I exclude a function that returns no logs in Sentinel?

Tags: azure, kql

I am writing a query that counts how many computers a user has logged into over the last 30 days. I need a daily count of each user's logon to a different machine for EACH of the last 30 days to get an accurate daily average from the logs, later I'll compare it to a threshold to detect an anomaly.

My problem is the query excludes all results of a user in my table if just 1 of the 30 days from a user returns no logs but the other 29 do. I want to be able to say something like, if no results (isnull? iff?) then skip this day and move on or be able to set the table values as blanks/0 so when I do the avg it will just add 0 to average.

Final table should return `TargetUserName`, `Avg` (sum of every day /30 excluding current day).

The code here displays all the days for testing and only 10 days instead of the 30 to shorten it up.

Right now it will correctly display users who have logs over all the last 30 days but if a user has no logs for even 1 day they are excluded from the final results.

```
let Event=(){SecurityEvent | where EventID == 4624 or EventID==528};
let d1=(){Event | where TimeGenerated between(ago(2d) .. ago(1d))| summarize DT1=dcount(WorkstationName) by TargetUserName};
let d2=(){Event | where TimeGenerated between(ago(3d) .. ago(2d)) | summarize DT2=dcount(WorkstationName) by TargetUserName};
let d3=(){Event | where TimeGenerated between(ago(4d) .. ago(3d)) | summarize DT3=dcount(WorkstationName) by TargetUserName};
let d4=(){Event | where TimeGenerated between(ago(5d) .. ago(4d)) | summarize DT4=dcount(WorkstationName) by TargetUserName};
let d5=(){Event | where TimeGenerated between(ago(6d) .. ago(5d)) | summarize DT5=dcount(WorkstationName) by TargetUserName};
let d6=(){Event | where TimeGenerated between(ago(7d) .. ago(6d)) | summarize DT6=dcount(WorkstationName) by TargetUserName};
let d7=(){Event | where TimeGenerated between(ago(8d) .. ago(7d)) | summarize DT7=dcount(WorkstationName) by TargetUserName};
let d8=(){Event | where TimeGenerated between(ago(9d) .. ago(8d)) | summarize DT8=dcount(WorkstationName) by TargetUserName};
let d9=(){Event | where TimeGenerated between(ago(10d) .. ago(9d)) | summarize DT9=dcount(WorkstationName) by TargetUserName};
let d10=(){Event | where TimeGenerated between(ago(11d) .. ago(10d)) | summarize DT10=dcount(WorkstationName) by TargetUserName};
d1 | join (d2) on TargetUserName | join (d3) on TargetUserName | join (d4) on TargetUserName | join (d5) on TargetUserName | join (d6) on TargetUserName | join (d7) on TargetUserName | join (d8) on TargetUserName | join (d9) on TargetUserName | join (d10) on TargetUserName | extend Avg = ((DT1+DT2+DT3+DT4+DT5+DT6+DT7+DT8+DT9+DT10)/10) | summarize by TargetUserName, Avg, DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5, DT6, DT7, DT8, DT9, DT10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a join kind = outer.

That way when there's no match, you'll still get rows from the other days.